# Logistic Regression Varimp Always Different From Other Models; Text Analytics R

Tags: r, text, analytics, logistic-regression

I've been running logistic regression, neural networks, naive bayes, and SVM models on my tweets dataset. I'm doing a sentiment analysis, where R is predicting whether a text is positive, neutral, or negative from training data.

I noticed that varImp is always the same for neural networks, naive bayes, and SVM. However, logistic regression has variables with very different variable importances. I'm just curious why that is? Is logistic regression not a good model to use for text analytics? Or are there times where it is suitable to use?

Comment: I would recommend posting your question to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tree classes (positive, neutral, and negative) in the outcome variable (i.e., sentiment class), you cannot directly use logistic regression model that is only appropriate for binary outcome. Other models such as neural network, naive Bayes, and SVM can directly handle the outcome variable that has more than 2 categories. Because the model specification is fundamentally different between the logistic regression and other models, it's not surprising that you got very different variable importance.